# Event not getting fired from a lwc custom lookup component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-dom, custom-event

I have used a custom lightning datatable which has a component displayed as a lookup

customLightningDatatable.html

```
 import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
 import lookupTemplate from './lookupTemplate.html';

 export default class CustomLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
     static customTypes = {
          fileUpload: {
             template: fileUploadTemplate,
             typeAttributes: ['acceptedFormats'],
          },
          lookup: {
             template: lookupTemplate,
          }
      };    
   }
```

Code for the lookupTemplate.html which has been imported

```
  <template>
   <c-customlwclookup object-name="Account" field-name="Name"
    parentidfield="AccountId"
    iconname="standard:account"
    parent-record-id = {value}
    onaccountselection = {handleAccountChange}
    class="childComponent">
   </c-customlwclookup>
</template>
```

lookupTemplate.js

```
   import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

   export default class lookupTemplate extends LightningElement {
       handleAccountChange(event) {
           console.log('here !!!');
           var AccountId = event.detail.selectedRecordIdValue;
           console.log("AccountId ::: "+AccountId);
       }   
   }
```

My problem here is that, my custom lwc lookup component has an event which gets fired every time a lookup value is selected

```
    handleSelect(event) {
    var selectedVal = event.detail.selRec;
    this.selectedRecord =  selectedVal;

    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('accountselection', {
        detail : { selectedRecordIdValue : this.selectedRecord.Id}
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

However, the handleAccountChange method is not getting called.

I am not sure why.

Comment: @Madurima Are you sure `handleSelect` has dispatched the event? Put a `console` at the end of `handleSelect`.

Comment: I did that already and it is coming up fine      {"isTrusted":false,"composed":false,"detail":{"selectedRecordIdValue":"0016F00002cy7eXQAQ"},"type":"accountselection","target":null,"currentTarget":null,"eventPhase":0,"bubbles":false,"cancelable":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":55596.4849999873,"srcElement":null,"returnValue":true,"cancelBubble":false,"path":[],"NONE":0,"CAPTURING_PHASE":1,"AT_TARGET":2,"BUBBLING_PHASE":3} @SachinHooda

Comment: I've updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `CustomLightningDatatable` is grand-parent of `customlwclookup`. Try dispatching the event with `bubbles & composed property set to true`,

```
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('accountselection', {
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
        detail : { selectedRecordIdValue : this.selectedRecord.Id}
    }));
```

I saw you've attached the listener handler to lookupTemplate. It should be on `CustomLightningDatatable`

```
<c-custom-lightning-datatable key-field="textCol" columns={columns} data={tableData} wrap-text-max-lines="3" onaccountselection={handleSelection}>
    </c-custom-lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: I tried that. Still same issue @SachimHooda and its not actually grand parent component.

Comment: That was exactly what it was. I though it was supposed to be on the imported html's js file. Thank you so much